# Nested route link not working React Router

Tags: reactjs, github, react-router-dom, netlify

I built my website on ReactJS to be SPA. I am trying to use React Router v.5.2.0. I have a sample app called ToDoList.js that should be at the URL on the portfolio page is below. For some reason it works fine on my localhost, but not when I deploy it to Netlifly and hosted on my Github. It doesn't seem to work when it's live [here](https://www.aubreyhlaverty.com). The back buttons on the browser also don't seem to work right either.

**Portfolio.js:**

```
<Link to="/portfolio/todo-list">here</Link>
```

The URL in the browser updates to the right URL, but it doesn't load the component. In my App.js file I have 2 types of routes so the sample app (todo list) doesn't show the top nav. It works

**App,js:**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
          <Switch>
            <MainRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <MainRoute exact path="/about" component={About} />
            <MainRoute exact path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
            <MainRoute exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <PortfolioRoute exact path="/portfolio/todo-list" component={ToDoList} />
          </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export const MainRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest}) => {
  return(
    <Route {...rest} component={(props) => (
      <>
        <TopNav />
        <Container fluid>
          <Row className="content-row">
            <Component {...props} />
          </Row>
        </Container>
        <Gradient />
      </>
    )} />
  );
};

export const PortfolioRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest}) => {
  return(
    <Route {...rest} component={(props) => (
      <>
        <Component {...props} />
      </>
    )} />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

All the endpoints along the `/portfolio` route need to be handled in one place, otherwise ReactRouter can't handle the nesting as it selects the Main one first.
See the docs' demo on nesting [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting)

---

Also, so that directly linking to https://www.aubreyhlaverty.com/portfolio/todo-list works, you should add a `200` redirect to your Netlify `_redirects` file, like [this](https://github.com/LukeStorry/netlify-router-params-demo/blob/master/_redirects). Might also help with your other issue.

```
/* /index.html 200
```